# Исключить впереди идущее слово из текста

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Я хочу найти слово в тексте, но только, если в тексте не встречается другое слово, которое идет впереди.
Например, я хочу найти слово "yes", но при условии, что впереди него нет слова "no".
Я пробую:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне выдается ошибка. Я не понимаю, почему я не могу вместе с ненужным словом сделать так, чтобы дальше шло что угодно. Я так хочу выразить, что между словом "no" и "yes" может быть что угодно.

Comment: Уточните, какой вид регулярных выражений вы используете. Не во всех видах разрешены подвыражения произвольной длины в заглядывании назад.

Comment: @vsemozhebuty в Intellij Idea я так хотела в поиске вбивать то, что мне нужно. Типа как в гугле, там можно исключать страницы, которые содержат какое-то слово.

Comment: и вот так он позволяет делать:  
     yes(?![\s\S]*no),     
если "no" идет после "yes".

Comment: все, спасибо, попробовала в Idea, там это проходит. Просто я до этого пробовала на сайте и там выставляла Java, не знала, что синтаксис настолько сильно различается.

Comment: regex101 поддерживает старые версии регулярных выражений Java, в новых версиях в просмотрах назад можно использовать квантификаторы `*` и `+`.

Answer (score 4):

На сайте regex101.com только опция `JavaScript` разрешает использовать шаблоны неизвестной длины в регулярных выражениях. Выбрав `Java 8`, вы можете использовать так называемый "просмотр назад ограниченной длины", то есть в таком шаблоне можно использовать "ограничивающий" квантификатор `{min,max}`, причём граница верхнего диапазона должна быть указана. Неофициально также поддерживался и `*`/`+`, но не было никакой гарантии, что такой шаблон будет работать.

Поддержка шаблонов с квантификаторами `*` / `+` / `{min,}` [официально появилась](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#limitbehind) в Java 13. Однако, рекомендуется использование только одного такого квантификатора в шаблоне просмотра назад во избежание нежелательных результатов:

> Java делает шаг вперед, допуская ограниченное повторение. Вы можете использовать вопросительный знак и фигурные скобки с указанным параметром max. Java определяет минимальную и максимальную возможную длину предварительного просмотра назад. Шаблон предварительного просмотра назад в выражении `(?<!ab{2,4}c{3,5}d)test` находит строку длиной от 7 до 11 символов, 5 разных вариантов. Когда Java (версия 6 или более поздняя) пытается найти шаблон предварительного просмотра назад, она сначала возвращает минимальное количество символов (7 в этом примере) в строке, а затем ищет совпадение шаблона предварительного просмотра назад, как обычно, слева направо. Если это не удается, Java отступает еще на один символ и пытается снова. Если шаблон по-прежнему не удаётся, Java продолжает отступать до тех пор, пока шаблон блока предварительного просмотра не будет найден или не вернется максимальное количество символов (11 в этом примере). Этот повторяющийся шаг назад по строке объекта убивает производительность, когда количество возможных длин предварительного просмотра увеличивается. Имейте это в виду. Не выбирайте произвольно большое максимальное количество повторений, чтобы обойти отсутствие поддержки бесконечных квантификаторов внутри блока предварительного просмотра назад. В Java 4 и 5 есть ошибки, из-за которых в некоторых ситуациях блок предварительного просмотра назад с чередованием или переменными квантификаторами иногда не работает. Эти ошибки были исправлены в Java 6.
>
> Java 13 позволяет использовать звёздочку и плюс внутри блока предварительного просмотра назад, а также фигурные скобки без верхнего предела. Но в Java 13 по-прежнему используется трудоёмкий метод поиска назад, представленный в Java 6. Java 13 также неправильно обрабатывает обратный просмотр с несколькими квантификаторами, если один из них не ограничен. В некоторых ситуациях может появиться ошибка. В других ситуациях вы можете получить неправильные совпадения. Поэтому для обеспечения корректности и производительности мы рекомендуем использовать только квантификаторы с низкой верхней границей в блоках предварительного просмотра назад в Java 6–13.

В общем, `(?s)(?<!\bno\b.*)yes` должно работать в данном случае: `yes`, перед которым нет целого слова `no`.

Если нужно найти слово `yes`, перед которым нет слова `no`, можно использовать

```
(?<!\bno\s)yes
```